# When Authenticating in Microsoft Graph and get querying, it outputs@odata.context and @odata.nextLink

Tags: powershell, api, jwt, microsoft-graph-api

So here is my code to get the AuthToken for my Tenant ID, this is from Microsoft and generates a JWT to use as authorization in the HTTP header:

```
function Get-AuthToken {
    
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        $User
    )
    
    $userUpn = New-Object "System.Net.Mail.MailAddress" -ArgumentList $User
    $tenant = $userUpn.Host
    Write-Host "Checking for AzureAD module..."
    
        $AadModule = Get-Module -Name "AzureAD" -ListAvailable
    
        if ($AadModule -eq $null) {
    
            Write-Host "AzureAD PowerShell module not found, looking for AzureADPreview"
            $AadModule = Get-Module -Name "AzureADPreview" -ListAvailable
    
        }
        if ($AadModule -eq $null) {
            write-host
            write-host "AzureAD Powershell module not installed..." -f Red
            write-host "Install by running 'Install-Module AzureAD' or 'Install-Module AzureADPreview' from an elevated PowerShell prompt" -f Yellow
            write-host "Script can't continue..." -f Red
            write-host
            exit
        }
    
    if($AadModule.count -gt 1){
        $Latest_Version = ($AadModule | select version | Sort-Object)[-1]
        $aadModule = $AadModule | ? { $_.version -eq $Latest_Version.version }

            # Checking if there are multiple versions of the same module found
            if($AadModule.count -gt 1){
            $aadModule = $AadModule | select -Unique

            }
        $adal = Join-Path $AadModule.ModuleBase "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll"
        $adalforms = Join-Path $AadModule.ModuleBase "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Platform.dll"

    }else {

        $adal = Join-Path $AadModule.ModuleBase "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll"
        $adalforms = Join-Path $AadModule.ModuleBase "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Platform.dll"
    }
    
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($adal) | Out-Null
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($adalforms) | Out-Null
     
    $clientId = "d1ddf0e4-d672-4dae-b554-9d5bdfd93547"
    $redirectUri = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"
    $resourceAppIdURI = "https://graph.microsoft.com"
    $authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$Tenant"
    
    try {
        $authContext = New-Object "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext" -ArgumentList $authority

        $platformParameters = New-Object "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.PlatformParameters" -ArgumentList "Auto"
        $userId = New-Object "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserIdentifier" -ArgumentList ($User, "OptionalDisplayableId")

        $authResult = $authContext.AcquireTokenAsync($resourceAppIdURI,$clientId,$redirectUri,$platformParameters,$userId).Result

        # If the accesstoken is valid then create the authentication header
        if($authResult.AccessToken){

        # Creating header for Authorization token, we dont necessarily need it, just the JWT auth token.
        $authHeader = @{
            'Content-Type'='application/json'
            'Authorization'="Bearer " + $authResult.AccessToken
            'ExpiresOn'=$authResult.ExpiresOn
            }
            # Write-Output 
            return $authResult
            # return $authHeader
        
        }
    }catch {

    write-host $_.Exception.Message -f Red
    break
    }
}
```

So basically at the bottom I use this JWT auth token from the function above and place it as an Authorization field in the HTTP header and it should return JSON from the Graph API:

```
$authData = Get-AuthToken -User acct@pennitout.com
$accessJWToken = $authData.AccessToken

$apiUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=displayName"

Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{"Authorization" = "Bearer $accessJWToken"} -Uri $apiUrl -Method Get -ContentType "application/json"
```

And the above code beautifully absolutely uselessly output it returns instead is:

```
@odata.context                                   @odata.nextLink
--------------                                   ---------------
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?=displayName&$skiptoken=RFNwdAIAAQAAABg6YWdyYW50QHRlcnJhbmV1dHJhbC5jb20pVXNlcl85MzA2OWJlYy0zZjFjLTRiNDQtOTZjMS
```

Please Help with this thanks I really appreciate

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check there might be issue that Token has expired, Please try to  generate new token and check it for the Odata next link which might have caused the error.
Here is the document for reference:[Token Duration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-overview#token-duration)

Comment: When I place the token in Postman and run the get query it spits out the data in JSON, but in the Powershell terminal its outputs that aforementioned Object containing URLs.

Comment: Can you please paste the Screenshot of the output and Request ID so that we can check from our side.